# Is the composing of functions always commutative?

Tags: functions

I have a question for my math study. It seems quite simple, but I just can't find a counterexample for the following:

The composition of two functions is always commutative

Could you help me with that?

Comment: The composing of function is almost never commutative. Consider $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=\sin(x).$ Can you see that $$f\circ g(x)=\sin^2(x)\neq g\circ f(x)=\sin(x^2)?$$

Comment: Did you downvote the question? That's not fair. I asked it properly, so what's wrong with it?

Comment: @Frans I wasn't the downvoter... you couldn't find a counterexample... why not just try to 'random' functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple. Take $f(x) = x^3, g(x) = 2x$. Then $f(g(x)) = (2x)^3 = 8x^3$, while $g(f(x)) = 2x^3$.

No thanks

Answer (score 2):

just check out matrix multiplication which is almost never commutative. But of course there are examples where the matrix multiplication is commutative so this a good source for both cases.

bests